# Weblogic JMS unit of work - groups of messages

Tags: jms, weblogic, messaging

I'm using Weblogic JMS. What I'd like to do is:

a) producer A produces JMS messages and put them on the queue ( groupA )
b) when processing each message from groupA I want to generate another messages ( groupB )

I've got 16 workers to process this messages.

Now, how I can ensure, that all messages from groupA will be processed before any message from groupB ?

Comment: How will you know when groupA is "done" receiving all messages or do you mean you just need something to forward messages from one place to another. You can use something like the Oracle Service Bus (OSB) to route/transform messages from one queue to another.

Comment: That's the trick :-) how to do that. I can't use anything more than I've listed in my first post, so I need to stay in the world of weblogic jms, spring etc. I was thinking about unit of order mechanism, as well as global transactions and some post transaction callback mechanism. But these solutions are not "clean"

Answer (score 3):

A bit late here but hopefully this will help anyone with the same issue. GroupA is effectively an Intermediate Destination. The JMS queue should have the default value of `Pass-Through` in the `Unit-of-Work (UOW) Message Handling Policy` setting. As your MDB processes these messages it needs to get the Unit of Work jms properties and reset them on the new message being sent for GroupB. This jms queue should have `Unit-of-Work (UOW) Message Handling Policy` set to `Single Message Delivery`. When the messages are received on this jms queue they will not be processed until all messages for a unit of work group are present i.e. all sequence numbers 1,2,3 etc and an end of message identifier.  Once they are all present the mdb will consume them as 1 object message and the individual messages will be contained in a `List`. It is then your job to code to iterate the list and process as you need.

[Weblogic Docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24387/uow.htm#JMSPG436)